# Do multi-column indexes affect the size of db-backup or size of mysql Server's RAM or HDD or CPU?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance, multirow

I have `database1` and `database2`.

`database1` does not use any special Index (rather that `PRIMARY KEY` indexes on `id` columns, but `database2` has been optimized using proper indexes (some indexes on multiple rows in some tables that have a lot of data).

**Suppose that they have the same data.** This is for a test.

Now the question is:

When I backup each of the dbs, will `database2` be heavier in size than `database1` (caused by the size of index files that have been created in `database2`)?

In other words:

Where is the affect of the large index files seen? Do they affect on database backup size or do they affect something in the internal MySQL server that the database is restored on that (say the server's RAM or CPU usage)?

I hope I've been able to tell you my exact meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes do not significantly increase the size of the database.

However while speed up querying they slow down data manipulation commands, inserts and updates, as the indexes need to be updated for each data change.

Comment: OK, thank you. But where is their affect? In server's RAM and CPU usage?

Comment: Their overhead is minimal as compared to the data. In general it is recommended to have a lot of RAM (up to 80% available) for dedicated servers so that data can fit in memory which provides the fastest processing speeds.

Comment: OK, so this is my answer: The data will be store in Server's RAM. Thank you :)

Comment: The data is always stored on disk, but is loaded into RAM for processing.